# Spring MVC forward appending request parameter values comma separated when we have same parameter name for topRequest and forward request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Spring MVC forward appending request parameter values comma separated when we have same parameter name for topRequest and forward request

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/details")
public ModelAndView details(@ModelAttribute final DetailsForm detailsForm){
  //DetailsForm contain a parameter called destinationId with value 1234
  final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
  //Some logic to get targeted destinationId (7890) using destinationId (1234) from detailForm
  mav.setViewName("forward:/search?destinationId=7890");
  return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(path = "/search")
    public ModelAndView details(@ModelAttribute final SearchForm searchForm){
  //Here I tried to get destinationId from model-attribute searchForm
  final Integer destinationId = searchForm.getDestinationId();
  //Then it returned me 1234,7890
}
```

Can someone please help me out how to resolve this. I want to get only 7890.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: nope the problem is still there. As far as I know the only way is to override the Spring class.

Answer (score 0):

I am interested in the answer also. I also hit this problem hacked it by adding a method:

```
private String getLastPartFromFormValue(final String value) {
    if (value == null)
        return null;
    String[] parts = value.split(",");
    return parts[parts.length -1];
}
```

Comment: This turned out to be a case of  repeated form variables for me; values end up as comma separated strings.

Comment: This turned out to be repeated param issue in my case. It is converted to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Just for sake of knowledge.

If you have a method, and you have a query param named *thing* and have an object annotated with `@ModelAttribute` and, in that object you have a field with the same name of your query param, you can expect that behavior.

For example:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/my-awesome-path")
    public String myAwesomeMethod(
    @RequestParam(name = "token", required = false) final String token,
                @ModelAttribute("formData") final MyFormData formData) {
//class fields and members...
```

And, in the MyFormData you have this:

```
public class MyFormData{
    private String token;
//other fields, getters and setters...
```

You will receive the query param `token` with the value duplicated and comma separated as well as in the `MyFormData` object.

The alternative is check the casuistic and change the parameter name or redesign if it's necessary.

In the example the query param name is changed like this:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/my-awesome-path")
    public String myAwesomeMethod(
    @RequestParam(name = "custom-token", required = false) final String customToken,
                @ModelAttribute("formData") final MyFormData formData) {
//class fields and members...
```

And the values are not more duplicated nor comma separated.

Cheers.